# publishing angular with dotnet core publish command

Tags: angular, .net-core, csproj

my current project stucture is

```
   solution dir
      -- clientDir
      -- serverDir
```

I am trying to publish the clientdir when server project is published, below are the changes I made to the `csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SpaRoot>$(SolutionDir)ClientDir\</SpaRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then added a target

```
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\myapp\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

But I am getting the error

> Unable to copy file "C:...\ClientDir\dist\myapp\scripts.js.map" to to
>   "C:\PublishDir\PubTmp\Out\C:...\ClientDir\dist\myapp\scripts.js.map".
>   The given path's format is not supported. ICollect.Public.WebApi

It is appending the full path of source file to the publish path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, thanks to this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2019

changed the relative path to

```
    <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.RecursiveDir)%(DistFiles.Filename)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
```